# How many line of code are in a program? (I know this is kind of vauge and depends but...)

Tags: java, php, javascript, c++, python

It seems when I try to research all I can find are how many lines are in Linux, call of duty, windows and other things that are massive applications with millions of lines of code.

Does anyone have examples of code size of applications that don't take teams and teams of people?

P.S.

I'm 24 yrs old and just starting to learn I feel like I got a really late start but I'm tired of sales and love technology so I'm just looking for something to gauge by.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: might be better answered at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why do you want to know that?

Comment: Literally speaking, the number of lines of code in a program is equal to the number of files in the application plus the number of line-breaks in all of them  ;)

Comment: the reason I ask is because well I'm learning javascript and when I look at a source code it's like 40K lines and all I can think is dang that's intimidation and it's kind of scares me away

Comment: It's only intimidating because there is functionality you are unfamiliar with. There are other factors that come in to play such as design patterns, but you will be able to read code more easily as you experience it.  Experience is a large factor in understanding code.

Comment: @T Mik It really depends on the number of features you need and how complicated they are.  Coding is an iterative process, and thus the code will grow as additional/different functionality is needed.  The program you are looking at is probably pretty in-depth, but as a new programmer you'll probably start with a simple application.  As the requirements grow, so will your code-base.  However, once you know the fundamentals, you can pick a chunk out of any size file and usually figure out what that chunk does.  Thus don't be intimidated by file-size!

Comment: http://www.ohloh.net/ has estimates of lines count and work for most popular open source projects.

Comment: How long is a piece of string?

Answer (score 5):

Code length depends completely on the type of the application you want to design. It also depends on the language of choice.  A program written in c will likely be significantly longer than say code in python.

It's never to late to learn!

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to programming, you might want to start with a great [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628) and a number of [practice problems](http://www.projecteuler.net). I'd recommend starting with C.

For these types of problems, you can write solutions which are 20-100 lines long. You can write the infamous "Hello World" in a mere 6(ish) lines. It is pretty rare that an individual works on something in their own spare time that is greater than a few thousand lines of code at most. Especially a beginner.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to gauge or give this type of information. Frankly, it depends.

Answer (score 0):

Between 1 and several million (roughly). It depends. One person can write a lot of code if given enough time.